# Grouping and update large database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a huge table containing 161 million rows. The table structure is `entryid(varchar), dater(date), region(char), detail(varchar), views(int)`, and the first four columns are together as the primary key. I want to do the following processing:

1. `detail` includes URL such as `www.google.com`, `www.google.ca`, `www.google.uk`, `www.facebook.com`, `facebook.com`, etc. I want to group those rows from the same domain, for example, using `LIKE "%.google.%"` for `google` and `LIKE "%.facebook.%" OR LIKE "facebook.%"` for `facebook` are good enough. But if update the rows, there might be duplicate key, how to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to sum the `views`? And is there a faster way other than `LIKE`?
2. I want to remove the `region` column and group the rows and sum the `views` and insert into a new table. How to do that in one command?
3. I want to group the rows (and update the `views`) by month.

Comment: It sounds like you need to build an aggregate table based on the existing detail table. Do you have some SQL that you have tried already?

Comment: Consider partition this table too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, for MYSQL, assuming that for *every* row, the detail field looks like www.something.com.

```
SELECT
   MONTH(dater),
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(detail, '.', 2), -1) as url,
   sum(views)
from table
group by 
   MONTH(dater),
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(detail, '.', 2), -1)
```

Or you could use a subquery to make it look a bit cleaner:

```
SELECT mth, url, sum(views) from
(
SELECT
   MONTH(dater) as mth,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(detail, '.', 2), -1) as url,
   views
from table) subq
group by 
   mth, url
```

Comment: Note that with 161 million rows, unless you have a beastly database, this may take some time to run. You probably want to do a `CREATE TABLE AS` as part of this.

Comment: What if `detail` field is not that simple? Basically, it will be like "something.%" or "%.something.%" or "%.something"?

Comment: Essentially yes - the SUBSTRING_INDEX functions just strip the first and last pieces of the string. This will be problematic with any string in that field that does not follow the pattern. You could try extracting the value using some of the other string functions in MYSQL (the documentation contains a complete list of what you can do). Another option would be add a "extracted_domain" column or something to the table, and run a process against the table beforehand, updating that row with your "extracted" domain logic, and then grouping on the new field.

Comment: One way to do that would be with a CASE expression for each possible pattern, using a regular expression to match and then the string functions to parse it appropriately.