# SQL update on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have asked this question [Grouping and update large database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069226/grouping-and-update-large-database-table), but I didn't get the answer for this.

I have a table: `name, date, detail, no`, and `name, date, detail` are together as PK.

Somehow I need to update `detail`, and it is possible that there are duplicate key. Thus I need to sum the `no` for the duplicate rows. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is only used for `INSERT`. So how to address this problem?

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm assuming there are two rows `name=A, date=B, detail=C, no=23` and `name=A, date=B, detail=D, no=45` - and you want to make it so if you update the second row's detail to be C, the two rows sum up to be a single row `name=A, date=B, detail=C, no=68` ? But only if the `name` and `date` fields also match?

Comment: That's right. It is actually merging those rows.

Comment: From your other question though I'm guessing this isn't 'just' two rows... you're aiming to change *all* the detail fields to something simpler (that you don't need to use LIKE on) and then for all the merging to happen?

Answer (score 1):

First things first, that multi-column primary key is probably a bad idea; as you've found out, it makes it difficult to manipulate the individual fields. What you ought to do is add an autoincrement bigint column to that table, which will become your new primary key, and your three-column uniqueness constraint can be a unique index instead. It should perform better... but it'll also allow you to do the sort of manipulation you need, as well. It'll let you perform modifications but still let you identify the original rows by their integer index.

If you do that, your "one-time update" can now be done safely, as long as you don't mind creating some temporary tables to work with. Something like this:

Create a couple of temporary tables with the same schema, but without the *unique* three-column index - you can have a non-unique index, because it'll help the queries you're about to perform;

Copy the records you need to process into the first table (including the unique integer primary key);

Update all the `detail` columns you need to update in the temporary table;

Use `INSERT ... SELECT` with `SUM` and `GROUP BY` to merge those records into the second table;

```
INSERT INTO temp2 (...whatever...) SELECT ...whatever..., SUM(no) FROM temp1 GROUP BY ...whatever...
```

Finally, delete all the records in the temp1 table from the original table (using the integer primary key), and insert the records in the temp2 table into the original table.

Comment: Multi-column primary key is not a bad idea, why do you think so.

Comment: @ypercube I used to like the idea of using whatever was "naturally" unique in the business model as the primary key; whether it was a string, or some combination of multiple columns. It did seem to make more sense than just adding a numeric PK "just because". But it makes things brittle when you have to make inevitable changes, just like the OP is doing right now.

Comment: The problem the OP has is because he has multiple rows with the same values of this key (which we assume he wants it be unique or primary). A simple `GROUP BY` will gather the data. (putting these data in the same table and removing the multiple rows can be tricky, yes.) I don't see how a surrogate key would help.

Comment: The surrogate key lets him identify the rows *even if* the business data in them changes. Right now he has records identified by (X,Y,Z), but he now has a business requirement to update Z, and then he has no way to select the original rows for deletion after he's merged them into a new record.

Comment: Right now, he seems to have no way to identify rows, he has no Primary or Unique Key. So, I agree, adding a surrogate key (temporarily or permanently) will help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Bad design. you should use surrogate id primary key and make these fields a composite unique index. If you want to reference this a table later what will you have? 3 extra fields as a foreign key in another table and an extra big index. How will you update the the detail field? If you said it before it's a big table it means that PK index rebuild. Disable the constraint if possible and if its not referenced already. Make select distinct or group by from your source table and make your update using this select.

---

REPLACE EDIT:

```
  REPLACE INTO table(name,date,detail)
  select distinct name,date,(select distinict detail from table) from 
  table
```

Comment: PK will not be updated frequently. I just want to make a one time update.

Comment: okay you can use REPLACE then. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Thank you. Can you give a simple example for this case?

Comment: make a copy of table before you run it and run it first there and read the doc carefully.

Comment: I think REPLACE remove the old rows, but I need to sum the `no` field.

Comment: I don't get it. The sum or the number of the field which has duplicates? is the no field the unique field there? if so then you should make it the PK perhaps. select max(no),detail,count(1) from table group by detail having count(1)>1. this will give you the last no with the duplicated row you can keep these rows and delete everything else where the detail in this detail and the no not in this max(no). I can update the answer if you want to delete the duplicates from this table where the detail duplicates > 1 rows

Comment: `no` is not unique. After update `detail`, there will be duplicate key, I want to merge them and calculate the SUM of `no` for all the duplicate rows.

Comment: select sum(no),detail from table group by detail having count(1)>1 this will give you the sum for each duplicated no